# payment processing in Paypal

Tags: paypal

I am processing payment wit paypal express . it works like the following .If payment is successful it redirects to a particular url in my web application with a lot of form variables set.If unsuccessful it redirects to another page in my system.

Is that there is to it. Cant there be fraud in this case by people redirecting deliberately to the Payment success page??

I am an experienced developer but not expert in payment processing

Any answer would be appreciated

Thanks
John

Comment: In the above, there _is a resource that determines success or failure_ before **"it"** redirects appropriately - the success or confirm page/s are _after_ that process. Hth..

Comment: If you are using Express Checkout you should be checking the result of the PayPal API call to know that the payment succeeded. With Standard Payments you can ask PayPal to pass you variables in the redirect back to your site via Payment Data Transfer (PDT), and you can also use Instant Payment Notifications (IPNs) to validate payments before offering goods or services.